# Node.js PDFjs fetching specific page using pdfjs-dist

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf.js

I'm trying to fetch the contents of page 4 of a PDF file using 'pdfjs-dist'.
I've tried to replace the 'pdfjs-dist' module with 'const pdfjs = require("pdfjs/es5/build/pdf")' but with no success.

What could be problem?
Thanks in advance!

```
const pdfjs = require('pdfjs-dist'); // Fetch PDF 

async function getContent(src) {
    const doc = await pdfjs.getDocument(src).promise // note the use of the property promise
    const page = await doc.getPage(4)
    return await page.getTextContent()
}

console.log(getContent('pdfs/Quantum.pdf'))
```

Answer (score 2):

It's too late to reply to this questions but let me add the solution that worked for me for those who will wish to implement the some issue.

This is the code that will work fine

```
// Install the latest version of pdf.js via npm i pdfjs-dist
const pdfjsLib = require("pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf.js");


  let pdf_path = "{RELATIVE_PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE}/sample.pdf";


   async function getContent(src: any){
    const doc = await pdfjsLib.getDocument(src).promise;
    const page = await doc.getPage(1);
    const strings: any = await page.getTextContent();
    let ITEMS_STRINGS = strings.items.map((item: any) => item.str);
    let PDF_STRINGS: string = ITEMS_STRINGS.join(" ");
    return PDF_STRINGS;
  }

  console.log(await getContent(`${pdf_path}`));
```

This will work fine